# open facebook app to login (meteor/cordova) iOS/Android

Tags: facebook, meteor

**1.)**

I have a native meteor app on my devices (ios/android.

**2.)**

I would like to enable a facebook login for my app (android/ios devices).

**3.)**

If the facebook app is installed on the device it **should open the facebook app to login**.

else it should **open the browser**.

**Problem**

there are so many facebook packages out there and its hard to choose one with the latest facebookSDK for meteor that works with cordova and allows me to open the installed facebook app. All packages had tested just opened a new browser window. can someone give me a hint for a working package that actually works?